# Как правильно использовать реляционную модель/запрос в yii?

Tags: framework, php, yii

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'idAuthor' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'id'),
    );
}

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'articles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Article', 'id_author'),
    );
}

        $post=  Article::model()->findByPk(1);
        echo $post->title;
        echo $post->login;
```

таблица1 Article: title, content, id_author.
таблица2 User:    id, login.

в чем ошибка?
Property "Article.login" is not defined.
как иправить?

Answer (score 3):

Я уже точно не помню. Так что могу и ошибиться. Но скорее всего вам нужно еще и указывать, что за связь вы используете.

То есть как-то так:

```
$post=  Article::model()->findByPk(1);
        echo $post->articles->title;
        echo $post->idAuthor->login;
```

Comment: Именно так и нужно через -> и указания связи :) ответу +1

Comment: поправочка:
`$acticle = Article::model()->findByPk(1);
$acticle->title; // название статьи
$acticle->idAuthor->login // имя автора `

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь можно при поиске удобно указывать:

```
$post = Article::model()->with('idAuthor')->findByPk(1);
```

Вернет запись `Article` вместе со связанной по `id` записью `User`.

Потом:

```
$post->idAuthor->login.
```

Вроде так.

Не сразу понял ответ выше. Небольшой личный вопрос: можно по связи обращаться к записи без вызова метода `with('имя\_связи')`?

Comment: можно. с `with()` генерируется запрос один общий запрос с JOINами, а без - создается дополнительный запрос. Поэтому без  `with()`  загрузка ленивой получается, т.е. получаете данные тогда, когда они вам нужны, а не сразу. Лично на мой взгляд, чем проще запрос, тем быстрее ответ. Поэтому я использую с `with()` в редких случаях.

Comment: @VasyOk, благодарю за очень аргументированный ответ)